# Dart Aqueduct generating flat joints

Tags: sql, dart, aqueduct

I'm working with the aqueduct dart framework and encountering some problems. As aqueduct does not have such an big community its pretty difficult to google porblems. 
If I have 3 Tables for example: User, Books, userBooksLikes. And I want to track in the userBookLikes Table which user likes what books. It has two forgeign keys, the IDs from Books and Users. Now I want to query just the Books which an paricular User likes (but not dislikes). How do I do that? I want to have an output that gives me just the events, without the Users. Is that possible in this framework?
Thanks :)

PS: If somone knows how to put Constrains to the database model so the user can not like AND dislike a book, I would be really greatfull ^^